# Gridview is not working properly when switching to FullScreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I've been trying to set the Gridview to the bottom when I switch the app to Full Screen Mode.  I must be doing something wrong because it is always on the top whenever switching to the full screen.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="820px"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgView" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="106px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"        
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"        
        android:columnWidth="66dp"        
        android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"        
        android:verticalSpacing="6dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" /> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/metal_frame" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone please show me how to make the GridView to show on the bottom for Full Screen Mode?

Thankyou so much

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try telling the GridView to be *below the imgView*, and not *above relativeLayout2*, like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="820px"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgView" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="106px"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"        
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"        
    android:columnWidth="66dp"        
    android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"        
    android:verticalSpacing="6dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" /> 

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/metal_frame" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The gridView is now a little below half of the screen.  How can I make it go all the way to the bottom?  I have tried this in code       gridView.setLayoutDirection(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);, but it is not doing anything.  Thanks a lot